# Setting Test Environment Variables With Vala and Meson

Tags: unit-testing, environment-variables, vala, meson-build

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

So I am trying to set environment vars for a database test in a vala project, but I can't find evidence of the variable anywhere. I also tried setting command line args but I couldnt access those either.

In my meson.build file:

```
test(test_db, test_db_exe, args : ['some_arg'], env : ['var1=some_env_arg'])
```

I then print out both my env vars and arguments with the following code:

```
 foreach (string va in GLib.Environment.list_variables()){
    GLib.Test.message(va);
}
foreach (string va in args){
    GLib.Test.message(va);
}
```

I don't see any evidence of these vars anywhere!

Here is the output of the test showing the environment variables and command line arguments printed to stdout:

```
─$ ./test-db                            
# POWERSHELL_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT
# USER
# XDG_SEAT
# XDG_SESSION_TYPE
# DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT
# SSH_AGENT_PID
# HOME
# DESKTOP_SESSION
# XDG_SEAT_PATH
# GTK_MODULES
# DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
# COMMAND_NOT_FOUND_INSTALL_PROMPT
# QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME
# LOGNAME
# QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR
# XDG_SESSION_CLASS
# XDG_SESSION_ID
# PATH
# GDM_LANG
# _JAVA_OPTIONS
# XDG_SESSION_PATH
# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
# XDG_MENU_PREFIX
# LANG
# POWERSHELL_UPDATECHECK
# XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
# XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP
# XAUTHORITY
# XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR
# SSH_AUTH_SOCK
# SHELL
# GDMSESSION
# QT_ACCESSIBILITY
# XDG_VTNR
# PWD
# XDG_DATA_DIRS
# XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
# SESSION_MANAGER
# PANEL_GDK_CORE_DEVICE_EVENTS
# DISPLAY
# CHROME_DESKTOP
# ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
# GDK_BACKEND
# SHLVL
# OLDPWD
# LESS_TERMCAP_mb
# LESS_TERMCAP_md
# LESS_TERMCAP_me
# LESS_TERMCAP_so
# LESS_TERMCAP_se
# LESS_TERMCAP_us
# LESS_TERMCAP_ue
# _
# BREAKPAD_DUMP_LOCATION
# TERM_PROGRAM
# TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION
# COLORTERM
# VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE
# GIT_ASKPASS
# VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE
# VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN
# TERM
# LS_COLORS
# ./test-db
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be looking in the `meson-logs` directory of your build directory. For my tests, `stdout` appears in `testlog.txt`.

Comment: I can see stdout when I run my test but the variables I added aren't in the variables printed. I updated the question with this output

Comment: That doesn't look like the output I get in `testlog.txt`. The Meson `test()` function runs the test and sets it up to run in an environment with the given variables, it doesn't compile those variables in to the test executable

Comment: Ahh I see, I wasnt running it with ```meson test test-db ``` command. Thanks!